# Random Integer List

Tags: c++, string, list, integer

If I had a list of integers separated by a space on one line (eg: 50 34 1 3423 5 345) then what would be the best way of making each of them a separate integer variable - collecting the list of integers with `cin`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In follow-up to sehe's answer, here's how you'd do it a little more verbosely (*ahem*).

The algorithms sehe used *basically* do this internally. This answer is included mostly for clarity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> myInts;

   int tmp;
   while (std::cin >> tmp) {
      myInts.push_back(tmp);
   }

   // Now `myInts` is a vector containing all the integers
}
```

[Live example.](http://www.ideone.com/t26HE)

Comment: +1 Hehe. Thanks for picking up on my work to explain the awkward STL-ese :) I suppose in practice, I'd actually advise this. Although, yes I do prefer the algorithm variant of doing things for slightly purist reasons.

Comment: I don't understand - how does this work if I enter all of the integers on one line?

Comment: @PigHead: Lines are irrelevant. `>>` reads as many characters as it can whilst they are valid for an `int`, then it stops. It also tends to ignore whitespace, so it'll be immediately ready to extract the next numeric-looking substring.

Comment: That's the only thing I actually needed to know! Thanks

Comment: @PigHead: No problem. iostreams are a bit rubbish. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> ints;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin), 
      std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
      std::back_inserter(ints));
```

Done. If you really need to explicetely read line-wise:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::string singleline;
std::istringstream iss; // out of loop for performance
while (std::getline(cin, singleline))
{
      iss.str(singleline);
      std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), 
            std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
            std::back_inserter(ints));
}
```

An `istream_iterator<int>` will repeatedly apply `operator>>(int&)` to the referenced stream (until the end of the stream). By default this will silently ignore whitespace, and it will throw an exception if the input operation failed (e.g. non-integer input is encountered)

The back_inserter is an *output iterator* that you can use with all container types (like `vector`) that support the `.push_back` operation. So in fact what is written there in STL algorithmese is similar to

```
std::vector<int> ints;
while (iss>>myint)
{
     ints.push_back(myint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - care to explain what... any of that does?

Comment: @sehe - Don't you think this answer is juuuuust a little too basic for the OP?

Comment: @Pete I disagree. This is exactly the type of code that should be used by beginners. The less of own code a beginner writes, the better.

Comment: @Pete: i tend to publish the core of an answer, and then take some time to embellish, often depending on the OP feedback

Comment: @sehe: I think.. you meant `std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)`.. instead of `std::istream_iterator<iss>(cin)` .

Comment: @sehe: Its not fixex yet. The type argument to `std::istream_iterator` should be `int`.

Comment: @sehe - the OP can't give feedback; he *fainted* when he saw your code :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: eeek... time for me to stop for today I guess. I bet I'd make a lousy tech-talk presenter with my typing ability (I tend to look at it the positive way: I think a lot faster than I can type :))

Comment: @Pete: now that is a bonus, sometimes. I do agree that my answer is purist, but then again, we are here to learn or teach, and I'd personally have *loved* to have been taught things like this when I was first checking out C++ with STL back in the days

Comment: @sehe: If only you were taught that you never actually use the STL.

Comment: @sehe -- I understand but from the OP's question he can't even *spell* STL yet :-) OTOH, I think it's very worthwhile to have seen your realization of the solution.

Comment: And the explanation. I hope it will shed some light. Jumpstart the learning curve. Pique interest. Good Things In General (TM); Good nite!

Comment: @Tomalak: I recognize the point, but remember I learnt this before 1998-ish. Back then STL was a 'thing' on it's own, the way I remember

Comment: @sehe: fair enough, but 1998 was a long time ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the man pages for `strtok( )` and `atoi( )`

Comment: Ew. It's the 21st century now, buddy.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I'm holding on to my investments in buggy whips, by God!